# Connect to a node with a String identifier

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I'm trying to write a generic OPC-UA connector with Eclipse Milo.
Reading data from nodes already works fine when I'm using numeric nodeIDs, such as *ns=0;i=2258*. In milo I can simple construct the nodeID like this for example:

```
NodeId nodeIdentifier = new NodeId(Unsigned.ushort(nameSpaceID), uint(nodeID));
```

and it works fine.

But when I'm trying to connect to a note with a string identifier of a production node that only have a string identifier like shown in this image

[image: Screenshot of a node with a string identifier]

the process fails with a `StatusCode{name=Bad_NodeIdUnknown, value=0x80340000, quality=bad}` exception.
I create the nodeIdentifier like this `NodeId nodeIdentifier = NodeId.parse(nodeIDString);`

and the parsed value looked like this:

*ns=1;s=t|023_Messwert*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, you can’t just decide to use a string-based NodeId because you feel like it. If the server is exposing it as an integer-based NodeId then that’s what you have to use, as is the case with the CurrentTime Node being identified by `ns=0;i=2258`.

Parsing a string-based NodeId via `NodeId.parse` will work fine as long as it’s in the right format. What value are you trying to parse?

Comment: Thanks, the first part has already helped to clarify a few things. I've updated my question for the second part.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that NodeId, it will parse just fine. If you get Bad_NodeIdUnknown in response to a read for that NodeId it means you have the wrong NodeId or there is something wrong with the server.